# React: Conditionally render a component in a route based on login status, without showing loading page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jsx

I'm trying to conditionally render a component based on login status. I click a link from a separate component to take me to home (The '/' route). If logged in, I'd like this to take me straight to the 'Logged In' home, and if not, take me to the 'Logged Out' home.

The problem with the loading page is it's quite clunky. The rest of the app loads instantly. The ability to go straight to 'home' in some app without having a loading page seems like it should be easy to achieve? Possible solutions could be:

- Conditionally rendering a route at some point, instead of a component under a route
- Displaying the last rendered component until data is retrieved, instead of a loading page.

EDIT: I'd like the '/' route to show either HomeLoggedIn or HomeLoggedOut but not redirect to another route, so that the url is the same for both components.

Current code with Loading page is below.

Thanks!

```js
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            loading: true,
            auth: false
        };
    }
    
    componentDidMount() { // check to see if already signed in.
        firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
            if (user) {
                this.setState({auth: user});
            } else {
                this.setState({auth: false});
            }
            this.setState({loading: false});
        });
    }
    
    render() {
        console.log(this.state.auth)
        return (
            <Router>
                <OuterContainer>
                    {
                        this.state.loading ?
                            <LoadingPage />
                        :
                            this.state.auth ?
                                <HomeLoggedIn /> :
                                <HomeLoggedOut />
                        
                    }
                    {
                        this.props.showPopupWithParams ?
                        <EditDictionaryPopup
                            dictionary={this.props.showPopupWithParams.dictionary}
                        />
                        : null
                    }
                </OuterContainer>
            </Router>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First off, you'll need to manage state across your app in order to store whether a user isLoggedIn, or isAuthenticated.  Trying to do it through managing state on your upper most component is going to create nightmares if your app ever gets even just a little bit more complex.  Try Redux or MobX or the React Context API.  I'll assume you create some kind of store with an 'auth' object checking to see if the user 'isAuthenticated'.

This being said, what you want is a PrivateRoute component.

```
// PrivateRoute.jsx
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'; // if you're using Redux!
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, auth, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render = {props => 
      auth.isAuthenticated === true ? (
        <Component {...props} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect to="/loggedOutHome" />
      )
    }
  />
);

PrivateRoute.propTypes = {
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
}

// this would map your auth object to the components props with Redux
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateRoute);
```

Then, you'll want to import this PrivateRoute component in your App component and use it, along with react-router-dom's Switch, on any route you want to keep private and add some rerouting:

```
// App.jsx
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import { default as PrivateRoute } from './components/PrivateRoute';
import { Landing } from './components/Landing';
import { LoggedInComponent } from "./components/LoggedInComponent";
import { LoggedOutComponent } from "./components/LoggedOutComponent";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
          <Route exact path="/loggedOutHome" component = {LoggedOutComponent} />
          <Switch>
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/loggedInHome" component={LoggedInComponent} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Now any link routing to your LoggedInComponent will check to see if a user isAuthenticated, and take them there if so, or, if they are not, will redirect to your LoggedOutComponent.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Jeremiah thanks for the response! One thing I didn't mention is I'm trying to make the route the same for both components. I want the '/' route to show either HomeLoggedIn or HomeLoggedOut but not redirect to another route. It looks like yours would instead show /loggedOutHome or /loggedInHome in the address bar. Do you know how you'd do the former? Cheers!

Comment: Hi Chris, sorry for the late reply.  If you want to use the same route but display different components based on some data and/or conditions, look at React's context api (https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).  That will do it for you.